# Can't insert element from array in mysql database with nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I actually have a problem saving some data from an array in a mysql database with nodejs.

This is my code

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
    var imageObject = data.data[i];
    var url = imageObject.images.standard_resolution.url;
    var id = imageObject.id;
    var sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS imageIDCount FROM images WHERE id = ?'
    var ids
    connection.query(sql, [id], function(err, rows, fields) {
        console.log(rows[0].imageIDCount);
        if (err) throw err;
        if (rows[0].imageIDCount == 0) {
            console.log(id + " doesn't exist"); // ### the ID at this point is always the last from that array
            //insertImage(id, url);
        } else {
            // console.log("ID exists");
        }
    });
}
```

This code run's when I get a response from an rest-api with the request-framework.

So my problem is that at the point I get the result from the count-query and there is no element with the specific id I get always the same id. 
I think that's because I use the same variable "id" there but how can I fix it ? I hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you're a victim of Node's asynchronous event loop. You're executing a synchronous for-loop and defining `id`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
    var id = imageObject.id;
}
```

This works in normal Javascript if you try and do something with `id`, but because the database module you're using runs asynchronously, that entire loop will have already completed before your first db query completes, effectively clobbering the value of `id`.

You'll need to re-write your function to behave asynchronously instead, or use something like [node-async](/questions/tagged/node-async) to help.

Here's a quick example of how that might look. Note that I didn't write your `insertImage` function for you; you'll need to rewrite that to support a callback as well.

```
async.each(data.data, function(imageObject, callback) {
    var sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS imageIDCount FROM images WHERE id = ?'
    connection.query(sql, [imageObject.id], function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) callback(err);
        if (rows[0].imageIDCount == 0) {
            console.log(id + " doesn't exist");
            insertImage(imageObject.id, imageObject.images.standard_resolution.url, function(err) {
                callback(err); // fires the callback to async
            })
        } else {
            console.log(id + " already exists");
            callback(); // maybe you want an error here too?
        }
    });
}, function(err, results) {
    // all of your db queries are completed
});
```

Comment: It works! Thank you for fast help. I suggested something like that, but I'm totally new to node.js.